# Google Tag Manager with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

When creating a new Google Tag Manager account, you create your container for web, IOS or android.

I am trying to integrate GTM into my PhoneGap application and I am unsure as to which option to choose.

While it is a mobile application, it's functionality is offered through Javascript, HTML and CSS and much of it's features have been implemented as though it is a web based application.

While the GTM docs provide guidance concerning IOS and Android integration, they don't seem suitable for a PhoneGap app.

Any advice would be much appreciated as always.

Thank you.